# how do I pass js variable value to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to pass a random number from html to php
the random number (generated by js), is displayed on the webform and  the user must supply its value on the form. php must GET this value and process accordingly.

In my webpage, i have this js and form action;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);</script>  
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="http://example.com/example.php&formvar=rnd">
```

In my example.php, i have

```
    <?php
        $rands = $_GET['formvar'];  
        echo "rands:" .$rands;            
    ?>
```

In this example, the value of variable formvar is always 'rnd' instead of the value of rnd

Can you please advise the best way to do this ?

Comment: I think in your php that should be `$_POST['formvar']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put data from a JavaScript variable into the document (including into form data), you need to write JavaScript that will do that.

You can't just use the variable name as part of HTML.

If you really want to put it in the URL for the form, you could do something like:

```
<form id ="contactform"  method="post" action="http://example.com/example.php">
</form>
<script>
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var form = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    form.action =+ "?formvar=" + rnd;
</script>
```

But you would probably be better off including it in the post data and using an input.

```
<script>
    var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var form = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = "formvar";
    input.value = rnd;
    input.type = "hidden";
    form.appendChild(input);
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried both your suggestions, but they don't work for me. I do assume I have done something wrong, so, for clarification, if i use your 'better' suggestion, where should that script appear ?

Comment: I have solved this issue now. Firstly the php needed a $GET and the form.action needed to be more specific .